# ¿Cómo buscar datos en HTML Web desde Google sheets sin alterar los datos en la hoja de sheets?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una barra de búsqueda en Google sheets para algunos reportes y funciona a la perfección a excepción de que solo una persona la puede usar ya que si otra persona busca un tema diferente se pierde la búsqueda previa, esto por ser una plataforma colaborativa claro.

Debido a esto subí mi hoja en HTML esperando poder hacer que funcione independiente de sheets para que se puedan hacer búsquedas simultaneas pero que sí tome la información de una base de datos que se encuentra en esa hoja.

Vi algunas formas sencillas de usar HTML como esta:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewreport" content= "width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title> sheets data </title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16EAqpai38p662r4sgKeCjQg9UQ34E25SSWQJXV-4XK0/edit?rm=minimal" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="700" ></iframe>


  </body>
</html>
```

Lastimosamente mi resultado ha sido tener la misma hoja con el mismo comportamiento pero en HTML lo cual no es lo esperado. Lo importante es poder hacer búsquedas simultaneas

Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna forma de utilizar esta barra de búsqueda sin que cambie los datos en la hoja de Google para que varios usuarios puedan utilizarla sin chocar entre si? Ya que si se escribe en la barra de búsqueda los datos obtenidos cambian y otro usuario tiene que esperar hasta que al actual termine su búsqueda.

Por acá dejo algunas imagenes para ques e entienda mejor y el link a un documento de ejemplo:

[image: Barra de búsqueda] (la barra toma información de otra pestaña para traer resultados aunque supongo que no es de relevancia esto)
[Enlace a la hoja de cálculo de Google](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16EAqpai38p662r4sgKeCjQg9UQ34E25SSWQJXV-4XK0/edit#gid=733779161)
[Enlace a la página web creada desde Google sheets](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyBK2H5BNOGxkolgQIkYxt0kp840hetqRJ66S5D3QmfH0a7sAXP1GAMAnhRu2cTTtGr/exec)

Llevo bastante tiempo buscando sobre esto pero no he tenido éxito en absoluto, espero alguien me pueda ayudar. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hola se puede hacer un script en html para levantar la información filtrada en html. Yo pude hacerlo parcialmente con un solo campo de busqueda pero en una tabla grande se me hizo dificil (me falta conocimiento)

Fijate este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8Bx5l5M3fE

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/388159)